# Magento admin panel is not working after stopping back up

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

I stopped the back up process unfortunately. After that when trying to log in admin panel I got an error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
Error log record number: 851173009070
```

I take the error report:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:91:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction";i:1;s:3113:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('UPDATE `admin_u...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('UPDATE `admin_u...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(632): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('UPDATE `admin_u...', Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/User.php(85): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->update('admin_user', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php(299): Mage_Admin_Model_Resource_User->recordLogin(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_User))
#8 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php(91): Mage_Admin_Model_User->login('admin', 'nicola123')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php(55): Mage_Admin_Model_Session->login('admin', 'nicola123', Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#10 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1299): Mage_Admin_Model_Observer->actionPreDispatchAdmin(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1280): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Admin_Model_Observer), 'actionPreDispat...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(505): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(152): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(409): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#17 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#18 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#19 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#20 /var/www/vhosts/ooh-lala.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(224): Mage::run('', 'store')
#21 {main}";s:3:"url";s:17:"/index.php/admin/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Can anyone help me to fix these these issue?

Comment: Do you have recent backups of the SQL database?

Comment: and is this a development project or is it on a live store?

Comment: No  activeDev that is the problem i am facing !!

Comment: it is live store. problem with admin panel only and front end is too slow ,i mean the web site

Comment: i don't think i should answer the question officially as i would only be guessing. i am wary of giving you suggestions especially if you do not have a backup of your database. so i guess you would have to look into resolving SQL locks.

Comment: if you did have very recent backups i would have suggest re-installing. Again, if this in on a live store I would take alot more precaution that trying to re-install.

Comment: can you please tell me how to resolve sql locks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Comment: Do you know which table is affected for this problem

Comment: No i dont sorry. please do some research on the General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded;

Comment: Try to login into admin panel from some other browser

Comment: @siby restart your MySQL server.