# Why does my script get this error?

Tags: python, mysql, cron

I have a Python script running every four hours. This is the crontab line:

```
* */4 * * * pi python /var/www/scripts/testProg.py >> /var/log/testProg.log
```

In the `/var/log/testProg.log` file I can see the following entry over and over again:

> Error 1205: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

My script does do some MySQL related things. Is this because the DB is locked by another process?

Comment: Try to debug it first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded -- If that doesn't work, add more details to your post.

Comment: Yes. Probably an open ended transaction or some kind of deadlock.

Comment: Some one may have done a transaction and did not commit, or trying to select data from table, and is locked. These are common database errors. You can get this checked with the DBA.

Comment: Think I found the source of the problem. Thanks for your inputs. I believe it is because after some INSERT and UPDATE statements the con.commit() method of the MySQLdb driver is needed before going to another DML statement.