# lock wait time out exceeded in java jdbc transaction

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I created this code for adding data for 3 tables. But I got an error, lock wait time out exceeded. In my database, I'm adding values for takerslist, q_enrolls and test tables. I'm getting some data from qBank and question tables. 
takerlist foreign key is stdId. I think it's not important here.
q_enroll's foreign keys are qId(References question table), qBankId(references QBank) and testId(references test).

```
@Override
public int add(Test e, Connection connection) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, RemoteException {
    String query = "INSERT INTO Test VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    Object[] data = {e.getTestId(), e.getTestName(), e.getTestFrom(), e.getTestTo(), e.getTotalQuestions(), e.getTestDate(), e.getPassMark()};
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        int res = DBHandle.setData(connection, query, data);
        if (res > 0) {
            List<TakerList> list = e.getListTakers();
            TakerListManagementModel takerListModel = new TakerListManagementModel();
            QuestionEnrollManagementModel enrollModel = new QuestionEnrollManagementModel();
            takerListModel.setAddCommonBehavior(true);
            enrollModel.setAddCommonBehavior(true);
            List<List<BankQuestion>> selQs = null;
            String testId = null;
            for (TakerList tl : list) {
                int resTakers = takerListModel.performAdd(tl);
                if (resTakers > 0) {
                    selQs = e.getListQBanks();
                    testId = tl.getTestId();
                } else {
                    connection.rollback();
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            for (List<BankQuestion> list1 : selQs) {
                for (BankQuestion bankQuestion : list1) {
                    QuestionEnroll enroll = new QuestionEnroll(bankQuestion.getqId(), testId, bankQuestion.getqBankId());
                    int resQList = enrollModel.performAdd(enroll);
                    if (resQList==0) {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            connection.commit();
            return 1;
        } else {
             connection.rollback();
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        connection.rollback();
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of db is it?

Comment: MySQL and I'm using mysql jdbc library

Answer (score 0):

You can set the lock timeout for your database explicitly (as probably your updates keep the transaction open for too long). For MySQL you can find the detailed instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded/6005564#6005564)

Basically you set it up with the command like this in /etc/my.cnf permanently with this line

```
[mysqld]
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120
```

and restart mysql. If you cannot restart mysql at this time, run this:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;
```

You could also just set it for the duration of your session

```
SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120;
```

Comment: I've execute SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120; and SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 120; in mySQL command line client. But i'm still in my problem

Comment: Maybe you need a bigger value?

Comment: I've set 1000; but still i'm in my problem

Comment: Also, if you want to use connection.setAutoCommit(true) use it before you execute your statements not in the finally block

Comment: @Kris He is restoring the auto commit status **after** he is done with his updates

Comment: I removed finally block. But i'm still in my problem

Comment: Mark R. you are right, haven't noticed earlier. @RSST have you tried the option with my.cnf and restarting you db?

Comment: Yes. I restarted. But after I removed testId foreign key, I't working well. If I added testId as a foreign key again, I got same error