# MySql can't update a specific record

Tags: mysql, timeout, sql-update

i am trying to update a single record in my DB.
i am getting

```
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
```

but when i try to update records with some other column , the update is return immediately.

also i cant delete this record

can you help me with this please .

Comment: A wonderful way to debug this transaction can be found here at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Comment: There may be an open transaction which still not committed.

Comment: can i force close transactions that running more then X seconds ?