# Why am I seeing a 'general error 1205 lock wait timout exceeded' in my Magento project?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have a multi store Magento web project. There I need to specify the categories for each and every store views in catalog --> manage categories. It was working fine, but from today itself suddenly it stopped working.

I can edit the categories, if the store view is "All store views".

If I switch it to any other store, such as store1, I can't make any change.

I have unchecked "default value tab", then if I choose Is Active --> NO, the default please wait loader will appear, and after some time the page throws an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try
> restarting transaction.

I am attaching a screenshot here

[image]

Why is it so?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Comment: Is there any other way without getting into mysql?

Comment: @hakkim Do you have access to mycnf file of mysql?

Comment: Nop. I don't have acces to the database, I got only magento backend and ftp access.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution,
I went to the phpmyadmin and run this query in sql,

> SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout =120

and everything went all right.
Thanks guys.