# Not found anything first time on Magento catalog search. General error: 1205

Tags: magento, search

When you find some keywords on my Magento store sometimes not appear anything but if you continue searching the same keyword finally results appear.

Variable 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout' was 50 and now is 100. Nothing happens.

Sometimes I get this error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:91:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction";i:1;s:3666:"#0 /home/nginx/www/includes/src/Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/nginx/www/includes/src/__default.php(64796): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/nginx/www/includes/src/__default.php(54128): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
....
```

I need help!

Comment: have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded

Comment: That solution does not solve my error