# How to update data in MySql table with grails?

Tags: mysql, grails

I have tried for days without success to update the records in my `MySQL` database using grails. I always get a `java.sql.SQLException` which is caused by:

Lock wait timeout exceeded

Here is the code I am using:

```
def campaignUpdater(id, details){
def dbData = Campaigns.get(id)
if(dbData){
      dbData.totalSent = details.totalSent
      dbData.totalQueued = details.totalQueued
      dbData.totalFailed = details.totalFailed
      dbData.uniqueClickers = details.uniqueClickers
      dbData.opened = details.opened
      dbData.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
      return true
  }else
    return false
}
```

I really need help as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lock wait timeout exceeded` exception is either caused if there is a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) and `Mysql` is unable to detect it, or if you have a very long running query.

You probably have a InnoDB engine problem. Most likely you'll need to kill some processes inorder for your queries to run properly.
See [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded) for more info.

Comment: It's hard to know what the problem is from the code when it comes to transactions in a database, I did some research and I edited my answer I hope it will help you solve the problem.