# How to fix 'Lock wait timeout exceeded' when deleting single row of MySQL table?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm making a website using Cherrypy, and I'm passing an array of IDs to a page to delete from the database. I don't seem to be able to delete any.

All other SQL statements seem to work, but running my `DELETE FROM MACHINE WHERE ID=1008` causes the page to fail to load, and after a while I get `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`.

```py
def delete(self, table, paramater=""):
        sql = "DELETE FROM {0}".format(table)
        if paramater != "":
            sql += " WHERE {0}".format(paramater)
        print(sql)
        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.db.commit()

delete("MACHINE", "ID="+ids[0])
```

Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOhFV.jpg

Comment: We need to see the table structure ... `SHOW CREATE TABLE MACHINE` .. InnoDB will table lock the complete table when ID column is non indexed

Comment: No image please execute the SQL command i have given..

Comment: @RaymondNijland ```('MACHINE', 'CREATE TABLE `MACHINE` (\n  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,\n  `CREATED_AT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,\n  `HOST` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,\n  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,\n  `SCREENSHOT` longblob,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)\n) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1')```

Comment: Ok there is a index so thats not the problem -> [How to debug Lock wait timeout exceeded on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-on-mysql)

Comment: Most examples I've seen of this problem occur with large numbers of actions, but I am only performing 2 delete statements

Comment: You still will have to debug -> `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` or and `SHOW FULL PROCESS LIST` and add that info in the question..

Comment: I can't run that because the DELETE makes the whole site lock up

Comment: use a dev machine (same os / same software versions) copy the db from production...

Comment: I mean that once the delete statement runs, I can't run the STATUS without restarting the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that I hadn't put quotes around the ID. The ID was stored as a varchar, so this was preventing it from obtaining the lock.