# Getting "Lock wait timeout exceeded" exception while updating a table in DB

Tags: java, mysql, database, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am executing the below MySQL UPDATE query,

```
Query query = em.createNamedQuery("User.unSubscribeUserByEmailId");
        query.setParameter("emailId", emailId);
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Whereas, `User.unSubscribeUserByEmailId` says,

```
query = "UPDATE User u set u.unsubscribed=1,u.unsubscribedReason='unsubscribed'  WHERE u.emailId = :emailId"),
```

One more thing I want to mention here is that the "User" table is the table frequently used/hit by other tables also. 
Also I'm not using a large chunk of emailId's updating at once, instead we have a foreach loop where single Id's are updating the unsubscription status like,

```
for(String emailId : existingEmailIds.getListItems()){
   unsubscribeEmailId(emailId, whitelistDomains, blacklistDomains);
}
```

Don't understand why am I getting "lock wait timeout exceeded" exception.

Comment: Is the user table indexed on emailId?

Comment: Yes, User table is indexed on emailId.

Comment: Looks like the table is locked by another transaction. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-on-mysql

Comment: Why try restarting transaction? However, no transaction is being created here in my code.