# ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction when deleting

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-8.0, server-administration

I am using MySQL 8 with InnoDB.

I have a table with about 6500 rows, when I try to delete any I get

> ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction error.

I have checked the processes using "show processlist". Nothing is running in the background, the same command works on another server, just not this one. I have also increased the timeout to 5000s and that still hasn't solved it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug Lock wait timeout exceeded on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-on-mysql)

Comment: @KenWhite thanks but unfortunately not, I have already been through that thread no luck! Is it possible it is an old lock? Or a server configuration issue?