# DELETE record mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table as an image below
[image]

I want to delete all records which have where condition but it's error

MYSQL query

```
DELETE FROM `DiseaseLogs` 
WHERE `UserId` = '098935f0-ef88-11eb-9baa-e9fb6cd272ad' 
       AND `logType` = 'vaccine' 
       AND `id` NOT IN (130 , 139)
```

Error: #1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug Lock wait timeout exceeded on MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000336/how-to-debug-lock-wait-timeout-exceeded-on-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
mysql->SHOW PROCESSLIST;
kill xxxx;
```

and kill which one in sleep. ( replace xxxx with your thread id )

Comment: i don't see any thread id but id so I tried kill 1 Unknown thread id: 1